# make an image move like a circle with a timer

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, core-animation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to let a view rotate forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803792/how-to-let-a-view-rotate-forever)

Hi everyone I would like to know if it is possible to move an image round in a circle with a timer. FOr example make it moves arround a circle with a timer that everytime it display a new position to the image. How can I do this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: yes you can but you have to provide more information and explain where is your problem. If you want somebody to do that for you I think stackoverflow is not the right place to look.

Answer (score 0):

make an anchorpoint for the image to rotate around? sorry you didnt provide alot of information....

This website covers exactly how anchor points work and how you can get an object to circle around that point http://www.qcmat.com/understanding-anchorpoint-in-cocos2d/

Comment: yes exactly.How can I do this please ?